# Meaning of スイッチ in the following sentence

Tags: meaning, katakana, loanwords, metaphor, sports

Context: in a boxing match, boxer A is fighting against the particularly tough boxer B. Even after having taken a lot of punches, boxer B is still standing. During a break, the trainer of boxer A says:

> タフネスにも**スイッチ**がある。ちゃんと殺しきれよ…　ガキ…

I think that スイッチ has a metaphorical meaning here. Since it is usually associated with switching things on/off, could it mean something like `a way to stop` or `a way to defeat`? How would you translate it? My translation attempt:

> Even toughness can be stopped in some way. You must totally destroy him, kid...

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: for more context, I can say that boxer B is a 打たれ強い boxer. He's an ex kick-boxer who says that boxing punches are 'light' compared to the kicks you get in kick-boxing. Being not afraid of punches, he advances to get close to his opponent even while being hit. He is an infighter, a boxer who fights at close distante from his opponent. [Here's the entire page the sentence is taken from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VeLW.jpg) In this page Boxer B has just got up after being knocked down by Boxer A. For further context, here are the following pages: [28-29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTwIQ.jpg) and [30-31](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GcEK.jpg). The manga is called [リクドウ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%83%89%E3%82%A6).

Comment: I think that スィッチ is a threshold. If you go beyond it, you can't stand.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E6%89%93%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8C%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%95%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%95%E5%89%87-%E5%BF%83%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%82%92%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E5%AE%9F%E8%B7%B5%E3%83%88%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8B%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%82%9B-%E5%B2%A1%E6%9C%AC%E6%AD%A3%E5%96%84/dp/4413009371　I found 心のスイッチ　打たれ強さ.

Comment: Is it really a question about Japanese? Do you have any doubts is what スイッチ means, or how it works in the sentence? Or is it a question how to express the idea in a natural way in English? For me, it seems a better fit for English.SE.

Comment: @macraf Whether a word is a 和製英語 or not is not something you should ask on English SE. This is about the metaphorical usage of the Japanese word スイッチ.

Comment: Um, anyway, actually this タフネスのスイッチ sounds a bit weird to me, too, and I would like to have more context. Perhaps pasting an entire page may help.

Comment: I think the sentence fits this site since the word スイッチ was used in a metaphorical sense by a Japanese writer in a way that an English writer probably wouldn't. Anyway, I'll update the question providing more context and the entire page.

Comment: @kimiTanaka Thank for your comment. I added the following page too for further context. Please write it as an answer if you think it's the correct interpretation.

Comment: @kimiTanaka Please try to avoid writing answers in the comment section.

Comment: @snailplane It wasn't meant to be seen as answer since some further reference had been still updated. I meant to post it as a comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, Boxer B was knocked down in 1st round because his body was not warm enough or something. I think that it's not normal in the real boxing though, the trainer worries about boxer B will get used to the Boxer A's hard punches as the round goes on if the **toughness switch on**. The trainer said the boxer A should have completely knocked him out in the 1st round. My interpretation.

After I read the  pages, boxer B was knocked down(flash-down: not so much damage since boxer B was not get used to the boxer A's punches trajectory) by boxer A's counter-punch in 1st round. So, boxer B doesn't carry over his damage to next round and he may recover quickly during the round interval.

Comment: Which article did you read? The sentence is from this manga: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%83%89%E3%82%A6

Comment: @Marco Sorry, it's not the article, I read the pages you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Even devices that produce great force will move or stop depending on the on / off of the switch.

In this case, I think that the phrase means that you should turn off or destroy the opponent's switch properly so that you definately stop the supply of his toughness to demonstrate; in other words, you should aim at the opponent's **weak points** or **vital points** in order to let the opponent never attack you.

Comment: No, you don't "cut off a switch" (unless you had a knife to remove it from where it was mounted). You can use a cut-off switch to [cut off](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cut-off) the supply of "toughness". That's really not a question about Japanese...

Comment: @macraf: I understand "to cut off the switch" is 和製英語, so I edited my answer. Anyway I think the given sentence refers to attack the opponent's weak points or vital points to destroy the toughness.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What is the 和製英語 which you refer to?